# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using  following code in my controller

```
BlueBusDB_Context db = new BlueBusDB_Context();
List<SelectListItem> li =new List<SelectListItem>();

li = db.M_BLUEBUS_STATES.Select(s => new SelectListItem {Text = s.STATE_NAME, Value = Convert.ToString(s.STATE_CODE)}).ToList();

ViewBag.State = li;
return View();
```

then in my create View I want to bind the dropdown and I am using as bellow

```
@Html.DropDownList("State",ViewBag.State as List<SelectListItem>)
```

I am getting the above error..

Comment: You could just use `ViewBag.State = new SelectList(db.M_BLUEBUS_STATES, "STATE_CODE", "STATE_NAME");`

Comment: In EF >= 6.1 you can use `ToString()`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you help me ..as your suggested answer worked for me but if I want to have a where condition then how i will change  new SelectList(db.M_BLUEBUS_STATES, "STATE_CODE", "STATE_NAME");

Comment: `var myList = db.M_BLUEBUS_STATES.Where(.....); ViewBag.State = new SelectList(myList, "STATE_CODE", "STATE_NAME");`

Answer (score 2):

Linq to Entities does not support `Convert` (see [supported funuctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx))

I would first create an anonymous type and then convert into SelectListItems to better seperate concerns a little bit:

```
li = db.M_BLUEBUS_STATES
       .Select(s => new { s.STATE_NAME, s.STATE_CODE })
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.STATE_NAME, Value = x.STATE_CODE.ToString()})
       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the regular `ToString` method instead of the one from `Convert` class:

```
li = db.M_BLUEBUS_STATES.Select(s => new SelectListItem {
     Text = s.STATE_NAME, 
     Value = s.STATE_CODE.ToString()
}).ToList();
```